# How to get color value from RGB values

Tags: java, android

I'm generating random RGB values

```
int r = rand.nextInt(255); // [0,255]
int g = rand.nextInt(255); // [0,255]
int b = rand.nextInt(255); // [0,255]
```

How can I convert these integers into another value (maybe int or hex?) so I can set a view's background color like so

```
int color = getColor(r,g,b);
myView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

What might the `getColor()` method looks like?

Comment: `Color.rgb(r, g, b)`??

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use the static method `Color.rgb`.

```
int color = Color.rgb(r,g,b);
```

Color.rgb

> Return a color-int from red, green, blue components. The alpha
>   component is implicitly 255 (fully opaque). These component values
>   should be [0..255], but there is no range check performed, so if they
>   are out of range, the returned color is undefined.